# Having problems publishing ColdFusion cfc file to DEV Server

Tags: visual-studio, coldfusion, publishing

I have a simple question in regards to publishing a ColdFusion .cfc file with Visual Studio 2015.  I have very little experience with ColdFusion.

When publishing from my LOCAL MACHINE to the DEV Server and running the 
application in DEV I'm getting an error in a ColdFusion .cfc file.  So I took 
the PROD version of the ColdFusion .cfc file and overwrote the version of the .cfc file on the DEV Server.  I then ran the application in DEV and executed the 
same function and it worked fine.  So then I took the PROD version of 
the .cfc file and used it to replace the version of the .cfc file in Visual Studio.  Then I published only the .cfc file to the DEV Server.  Then I ran the application in DEV and tried to execute the same function and the error reappears.  I did a diff on the two files and they seem identical.  Can someone explain why this would occur?

Thanks,

Pete

The error message is:  Invalid data '' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER.

Comment: The error message would help.   Is your dev server pointing at the prod database?  It not it could be a data issue. Also if you are caching in prod that might be hiding the error.

Comment: Added error message.

Comment: The error means you are trying to put a blank value in the cfqueryparam that is expecting an integer.  Put some logging in there to see the values that are passing to the query.  What I do in these situations is to put a cfmail tag inside the function and email myself the function arguments.  That will tell you what data is missing.